# Polymer Dart Strong Mode and Mixins is forcing weird code designs

Tags: polymer, dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

We started to use Dart's Strong mode with our polymer dart code and honestly it looks terrible.  It looks so terrible that I need a second opinion on the matter.  It cant be this ugly looking, it honestly cant.

So We were creating a bunch of PolymerDart views using some mix ins for generic code.  This generic code is reused everywhere so hence why we made it a mixin.

Our old design:

```
abstract class MyModel{ ... }
class SubModel extends MyModel with JsProxy{ ... }


@behavior
abstract class MyBehavior implements PolymerBase {
  @Property(notify:true)
  MyModel model = null;
  // ....
}

@PolymerRegister("my-component")
class MyViewModel extends PolymerElement with MyBehavior {
  @Property(notify:true)
  SubModel model = null;
// ...
}
```

The purpose was to have a generic model to represent information and we leverage it in the behavior.  Since SubModel extends it, we can slot anywhere normally and the behavior would work.  My colleague says this is a huge *NO* and I am confused as to why.  He said it a Polymer Issue, so when we leave Polymer it will be able to be done sort of.

He then pushed through the code base a refactor so it works.

```
@PolymerRegister("my-component")
class MyViewModel extends PolymerElement with MyBehavior {
  @Property(notify:true)
  MyModel model = null;  // <-- changed to parent type from Behavior

  //example reference
  void test(){
    int id = (model as SubModel).id;  // <-- using AS to explain what it really is.
  }
}
```

Now he put this EVERYWHERE, updated all references of `model.id` with `(model as SubModel).id`.  I think this is ugly and just plain wrong.  (Granted I get that feeling with everything PolymerDart).

Is this really how this kind of thing is done when dealing with Mixins?  Since The mixin already has that definition, we shouldn't need it in the MyViewModel code either.

Can someone explain this to me as to why this is the right thing according to strong mode?  Why must this change occur?  While I trust in my colleague, something does seem off and I would like a deeper understanding.  I believe, that he is correct that maybe it is because entirely due to Polymer Dart, but maybe there is a way to circumventing all property renames, and using `(.. as Whatever)` everywhere.

**analysis_options.yaml:**

```
analyzer:
  strong-mode: true
```

*Edit:*  The reasoning was that since the Model is defined as a property in the behavior, it is non-mutable.  We cant override the type in the MyViewModel class.  Since SubModel extends MyModel, It *should* be allowed to exist.

Comment: Looks as the problem origins from `SubModel` being replaced with `Model` or `Model` not having `ìd`. So for me the strong mode warning is motivated. It helps other devs understanding the code.

Comment: You are right.  Model doesnt have `id` so it needs to be cast, which leads me as to why it was switched out.  When talking to him, he was saying that because both `MyModel` in the behavior was set with `@property` it was creating issues reassigning the type when trying to do: `@property SubModel model`, saying the the reasoning is Polymer related. He showed that this would not be the case when leveraging it through AngularDart, which begs me to question, why.  Why does the strong model property annotation cause such a hub-bub.

Comment: Hi, have you considered using Dart's [`covariant` keyword](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/sound-problems#the-covariant-keyword)? I only skimmed through your question and I'm not that familiar with Polymer.dart, but your issue seems like a good case for covariant.

Comment: @filiph The issue i have noticed with covariant is that you use it for 2 siblings of the same base class.  Where as my behavior using the base class.  I cant use covariant to override the type of a base class.  This is really a super terrible issue developed specifically around the property annotation of Polymer it seems moreso than a strong mode error I think.